# GR8767 Question 54

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group, and fix a an element $G$. The function $f$ from $G$ to $G$ defined by $f(x) = axa^2$
is a group homomorphism if and only if

A. $G$ is abelian;
B. $G = {e_G}$;
C. $a = e_G$;
D. $a^2 = e_G$; 
E. $a^3= e_G$

I know that the answer is E. I just do not know how to get to that answer. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f(x) = axa^2$ is a group homomorphism. Then $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for any $x,y \in G$, so

$$a(xy)a^2 = (axa^2)(aya^2),$$

or, by associativity,

$$axya^2 = axa^3ya^2.$$

Multiplying by $(ax)^{-1}$ on the left and $(ya^2)^{-1}$ on the right gives $a^3 = e_G$.

The converse follows by a similar argument.